# Overwriting toString function

Tags: javascript, tostring

```
function toString(obj) {
        return {}.toString.call(obj);
    }
```

I see this function in some open source javascript project. What is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces a result like `[object Number]` or `[object String]`  when used on numbers and strings, but the exact purpose of it depends on how it is used.

Look for examples of its usage within code you are looking at, that should give you a better idea of what it's for.

It could be used as a method to identify the type of an unknown variable a more sophisticated alternative to `typeof` as it returns results like `[object HTMLBodyElement]`

Answer (score 2):

Let's take each component in turn:

**`return`:** returns whatever value the `call` function returns.

**`{}`:** This declares an empty object.

**`.toString`:** the `toString` function on every object.

**`.call`**: method calls a function with a given `this` value (see [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). In this case, the `this` is the `obj` passed into the `toString` function.

Answer (score 1):

[jsve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640314/2319844) gives you the 'what'. The 'why' is: to use the base `Object.toString()` on the input object, even if that object's own prototype has a more specialized `toString()` in place.