# js object check if toString is defined

Tags: javascript, tostring

I am building a json formatter application. and I am very much confused by the `toString` method.

let's say I have an object. I parse it into a `ul` `li` Dom tree to illustrate. and I add a label based on the **variable type**.

```
function getText(val){
    v = val.toString();
    let p = document.createElement('span');
    p.innerText = v;
    return p;
}
```

it works fine for common types such as `string`, `number`, etc. but, when working with user defined object:

```js
f = new TestClass();
console.log(getText(f));
{/* <span>[object Object]</span> */}
```

it produced a strange result. I have read relevant posts such as [Overwriting toString function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640270/overwriting-tostring-function), and understand how it works.

basically, I understand javascript object's `toString` method the same as python's dunder `__str__`, for example, when something like:

```js
`${f}`
```

is implemented `TestClass.toString` is called. then I tried to see where it is defined, what is the base class it inherits from, but I got nothing. `super is not allowed in this context`.

---

for user defined object, how can I determine whether a costume `toString` is defined on instance or not?

something like:

```js
class TestClass1{
    
}

class TestClass2{
    toString(){

    }
}

console.log(new TestClass1().toString === undefined)
// should return true
console.log(new TestClass2().toString === undefined)
// should return false
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in their [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) if the `toString()` is the same as `Object`'s or not:

```
TestClass.prototype.toString === Object.prototype.toString
```

Or, via [an instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf#non-object_coercion):

```
// preferred method:
Object.getPrototypeOf(testClassInstance).toString === Object.prototype.toString
// alternative accessing __proto__ directly:
testClassInstance.__proto__.toString === Object.prototype.toString
```

Demo:

```js
class TestClass {
  toString() { return 'I am TestClass'; }
}
const tc = new TestClass();

class ClassWithoutToString { }
const cwts = new ClassWithoutToString();

console.log(
  TestClass.prototype.toString === Object.prototype.toString,
  ClassWithoutToString.prototype.toString === Object.prototype.toString
);
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(tc).toString === Object.prototype.toString,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(cwts).toString === Object.prototype.toString
);
```

Comment: This is good. I just learned via experiment that you can say `class Foo extends Object {}`, call super in the constructor, and use object methods via super.